# For any triangle $ABC$ what is the minimum value $\sum \frac{\sqrt{\sin A}}{\sqrt {\sin B}+\sqrt{\sin C}-\sqrt{\sin A}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

The problem:

*Let $ABC$ be an arbitrary triangle.  What is the minimum value $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{\sin A}}{\sqrt {\sin B}+\sqrt{\sin C}-\sqrt{\sin A}}?$$*

I need a little help in simplifying the problem, so that I can finish it on my own. I do know that we can simply it before using the $\sum$, but  I don’t know how.

Comment: First point : the problem is equivalent to find the minimum value of $\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}$  using the law of sine .

Comment: Maybe multyplyng by all the conjugates help to clear the denominator ([wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%28x%29%2Bsqrt%28y%29%2Bsqrt%28z%29%29*%28sqrt%28x%29%2Bsqrt%28y%29-sqrt%28z%29%29*%28sqrt%28x%29-sqrt%28y%29%2Bsqrt%28z%29%29*%28sqrt%28x%29-sqrt%28y%29-sqrt%28z%29%29))

Comment: Secondly put $\sqrt{a}=x$ and $\sqrt{b}=y$  and $\sqrt{c}=z$ and use the ravi substitution . https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution/

Comment: @Aditya Can you end now ?

Comment: @The.old.boy I read the link you gave, but I can’t see how that applies. I mean I am sure it does work, the equations seem to be analogous yet they aren’t exactly the same